# Indexing in fread(): Is there a way to set the minimum index to be returned?

Tags: c, indexing, pthreads, fread

## Context:

I am trying to read a file, and find out what character is where in the section that I am reading. For the grand scheme of this part of the program, I am using pthreads and fread().

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
  excess=( fread( thread_data[i].buffer, 1, 30, f ) );
  printf("\n\nSegFault 1 \n\n%s\n\n\n", thread_data[i].buffer);
  printf("\n\nSegFault 2 n\n%s\n\n\n", &thread_data[i].buffer[10]);
```

To put everything into context, the first statement is printing the entire buffer, including leftover garbage is I am not setting up a null-terminator quite yet.

Then, we I call the second printf, I am getting everything from the 10th character in buffer to the last character of buffer. For example:

```
 frist printf:    1234567890 abcdefgh
 second printf:   abcdefgh
```

## Question:

How do I index buffer such that I can retrieve a single character to play with? If we look at the above example, when I call:

```
&thread_data[i].buffer[10]
```

I am expecting to return `' '`, that is, a space

Comment: This has nothing to do with `fread()`.  Or with pthreads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the indexing mostly right, but the printing wrong.  You can reference the **`char`** at index 10 in the buffer like so:

```
thread_data[i].buffer[10]
```

If you instead take the address of that `char`, the resulting `char *` can be used to refer to the **C string** consisting of the tail of `thread_data[i].buffer` starting at index 10.  So try this:

```
printf("\n\nSegFault 2 n\n%c\n\n\n", thread_data[i].buffer[10]);
```

Note the small changes *both* to the format string and to the argument.

Comment: So I was looking at it, and this does what I was expecting it to do. However, I am now stuck on the premise of storing this character in a structure (which is why I was trying to print it in the first place). Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: You can store individual chars in a struct member of type `char`.  You can also store an array of chars in a struct member of type `char[n]` for some `n`.  If you are more familiar with a higher-level language than C, then it might be C's lack of a string type that's throwing you. `char` represents exactly one character, and  C "strings" are not a bona fide type of their own, just a standardized convention built on top of the `char` type.